# How to make the page background black with div message notification on top

Tags: javascript, html

i finally made my div popup message work but i don't know how to make the black background `opacity:0.5;` when i click on that link `message()`. So when i click on that link i want the background becomes black with a low opacity + i want the popup div to come up.

This is the code that i use:

```
 function message() {
    el = document.getElementById("message");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}

<a href='#' onclick='message()'><img id="english" src="images/english.png"></a>
    </div>




<div id="message">
     <div>

          <p id="messagetext">English is set to the default language.</p>
          <a href='index-eng' onclick='message()' id="messagebtn">OK</a>

     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The easiest way of doing this would be to toggle a class on the container element and use css to style the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you asking about is called Modal Box.

[Sebastian Kissling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9153867/sebastian-kissling) answered with a good simple [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48654589/7128891). But if you want more complex solution, then check this guide from W3Schools: [How TO - CSS/JS Modal](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp).

UPDATE: edited Sebastian's answer. So now you can close message by clicking on background(and go to another url).

```js
function messageOffBg(event) {
  if (!document
      .getElementById("message")
      .contains(event.target)) {
    messageOff();
    window.location.href = 'https://www.wikipedia.org/';
  }
}

function messageOn() {
  document.body.setAttribute("class", "background");          
  document.getElementById("message").style.visibility = "visible";
          
  setTimeout(function(){
      document.addEventListener('click', messageOffBg)
    },
    300);
}

function messageOff() {
  document.body.setAttribute("class", "");          
  document.getElementById("message").style.visibility = "hidden";  
  document.removeEventListener('click', messageOffBg);
}
```

```css
.background {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.msg {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href='#' onclick='messageOn()'><img id="english" src="images/english.png"></a>

  <div id="message" class="msg">
       <div>
            <p id="messagetext">English is set to the default language.</p>
            <a href='#' onclick='messageOff()' id="messagebtn">OK</a>
       </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's not a good enough answer because i said in my post that i don't know the jquery/javascript code. But thanks for your time !

Comment: No problem. Just, for future, if you use css library like w3css or bootstrap or else, you can search for "modal" in that css library (it will be much easier to use).

Comment: i want it to click on .msg black background then go to url, do you know how to do that?

Comment: I updated my answer. So inside function `messageOffBg` you can see `window.location.href = 'https://www.wikipedia.org/';`. So when you click on black background, the message will close and you will go to wikipedia site. Just replace wikipedia url with your url.

Comment: Its weird that it works in code snippet but on my website it doesn't www.gester.nl

Comment: It doesn't work, can you inspect it for me please? The code is only in the index page. I can make it work in another way but its not in the javascript way as you can see in the other pages when you click the background it works

Comment: Also i want this code to work only if the popup is open 

`   document.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
   var key = e.which||e.keyCode;
   switch(key){
      //enter
      case 13:
         document.getElementById("messagebtn").click();
      break;
      //space
      case 32:
         document.getElementById("messagebtn").click();
      break;
      //escape
      case 27:
         document.getElementById("messagebtn").click();
      break;
     
   }
});`

Comment: It's possible to click on the html/body behind the background but not on the background itself

Comment: To hotfix this code to work on your site just change `"message"` to `"messagetext"` in function `messageOffBg(event)`

Comment: About code for key:
1) move outside and name `function(e){...}`
2) suppose you named it `keyCloseMsg(e)`, then 
  add `document.addEventListener("keyup", keyCloseMsg)` at the end of function `mesageOn()` and
  add `document.removeEventListener("keyup", keyCloseMsg)` at the end of function `mesageOff()`

Comment: I have so much respect and am very thankfull for your help. The messagetext works perfect, why this works i dont understand but it works. 

The code for key works only with using enter(case 13:) But it's doing something weird with the space(case 32:) and with escape (case:27). Space and Escape only work when you click Space twice, Escape twice or the combination of Space and Escape. Do you know why this is acting so weird? Cause the enter works fine, i changed the order of cases but it doesn't change anything

Comment: `function keyCloseMsg(e){

  document.addEventListener("keyup",function(e){
   var key = e.which||e.keyCode;
   switch(key){
      //enter
      case 13:
         document.getElementById("messagebtn").click();
      break;
      //space
      case 32:
         document.getElementById("messagebtn").click();
      break;
      //escape
      case 27:
         document.getElementById("messagebtn").click();
      break;
     
   }
});
 }`

Comment: Last question, i use this code(next comment) for my div tiles to open up.


How can i use a code that also lets it go to the next page when i touch the background behind the dialog with touch devices?

Comment: `if (!("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)) {
    $(document.documentElement).addClass("no-touch");
}
$('html').on('touch touchend', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('over');         
});
 `

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
function message() {
    container = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    container.classList.contains("background") ? container.setAttribute("class", "") : container.setAttribute("class", "background");
    el = document.getElementById("message");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
```

```css
.background {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.msg {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href='#' onclick='message()'><img id="english" src="images/english.png"></a>

  <div id="message" class="msg">
       <div>
            <p id="messagetext">English is set to the default language.</p>
            <a href='#' onclick='message()' id="messagebtn">OK</a>
       </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Works good thanks. Only i changed background:white to the same background as .background. Then i put position fixed in .background. Which makes it perfect. Thanks for your time and answer

Comment: I am now figuring out. If i would left click on the black background behind the dialog, it needs to go to a link? Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Because it doesn't work with  

$("#message, .msg").on('click', function(){
     window.location = "http://www.google.com/";    
});

Comment: i want it to click on .msg black background then go to url, you know how

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function message(){
      el = document.getElementById('message');
   fade = document.getElementById('fadebg');   
   el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
   fade.style.visibility = (fade.style.visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
  }
```

```css
#fadebg{position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);top:0;left:0;visibility:hidden;}
   #message{position:absolute;width:30%;top:20px;left:50%;margin-left:-15%;background:#fff;text-align:center;padding:10px;z-index:1;visibility:hidden;}
```

```html
<a href='#' onclick='message()'><img id="english" src="images/english.png">Click to Open</a>
 <div id="message">
   <div>
     <p id="messagetext">English is set to the default language.</p>
     <a href='#' onclick='message()' id="messagebtn">OK</a>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div id="fadebg"></div>
```

Comment: Works good but i choice for the answer above this one. Thanks for your time and answer

Comment: i want it to click on .msg black background then go to url

Answer (score 0):

like this.

```js
document.getElementById("x").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.toggle("my-class");
});
```

```css
body {
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  background-color: rgba(255, 109, 0, 0.8);
}
.my-class {
  background-color: rgba(255, 109, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<button id="x">
press me
</button>
```